# Read data from nested LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, android, hashmap, linkedhashmap

1st level linkedhashmap

```
LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>> level_1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

2nd level linkedhashmap`

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> level_2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    level_2.put("abcd", R.drawable.abcd);
```

put method

```
level_1.put("ABCD", level_2);
```

Now I have to read data from above code

```
LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>> abcd;
```

I have 2 intents - level_1 and level_2

```
abcd.get(level_1).get(level_2)
```

this gives a warning

> LinkedHashMap(String, Integer) may not contain objects of type integer

I want to read the String and Integer values separately so that i can populate textView and Imageview.

In summary

how to read the integer and stringfFrom innermap) separately from

```
LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine :

```
LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>> level_1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> level_2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
level_2.put("l2", 2);
level_1.put("l1", level_2);
System.out.println(level_1.get("l1").get("l2"));
```

Your problem is that when you call `get()` method you should actually give as an argument the key to which you mapped your value. In this case your key is of the String type.

Comment: Thank you. Can I get a output of the key, and value of inner map using only the key of outer map?

Comment: @DharshanSiva Sorry, I can't understand you, can you describe it using the actual keys and values?